# What is the map $f^*: Br(Y)\to Br(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, brauer-group

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes.
Let $Br(X)$ be Brauer group of $X$.
I heard $Br(-)$ is functrial, that is, there is induced map $f^*: Br(Y)\to Br(X)$.

How $f$ induces $f^*$, in other words, what is the map $f^*$ exactly ?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: What definition of $\mathrm{Br}(X)$ you are using?

Comment: The same as this one https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445304/what-is-a-definition-of-ap-v-in-the-definition-of-brauer-manin-obstruction?noredirect=1#comment1150560_445304. Define Brauer group of local ring and define$Br(X)$ as intersection of every local ring of $X$.

Comment: @Sasha The same defined is also in this pdf . https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/master/2017-2018/ivokok-thesis2.0.pdf

Comment: Then study the case of a local morphism of local rings first.